# python element tree extract value not working

Tags: python, xml, celementtree

I'm trying to extract the values in `<paste_key>` with ElementTree and i'm getting the following error. Can anyone help show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from pastebin import PastebinAPI
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
import time

x = self.apiobject.pastes_by_user(api_dev_key=self.DEVKEY, api_user_key=self.userkey)
print x
x = ET.fromstring(x)


for key in list(x):
  self.pastekeys.append(key.find('paste_key').text)
print self.pastekeys
```

Error output:
`junk after document element: line 13, column 0`

Sample Data that would exist in `x`

```
<paste>
<paste_key>afafafaf</paste_key>
<paste_date>1508796842</paste_date>
<paste_title>1508796842</paste_title>
<paste_size>36096</paste_size>
<paste_expire_date>0</paste_expire_date>
<paste_private>2</paste_private>
<paste_format_long>None</paste_format_long>
<paste_format_short>text</paste_format_short>
<paste_url>https://pastebin.com/afafafaf</paste_url>
<paste_hits>0</paste_hits>
</paste>
<paste>
<paste_key>asdfasdf</paste_key>
<paste_date>1508796842</paste_date>
<paste_title>1508796842</paste_title>
<paste_size>36096</paste_size>
<paste_expire_date>0</paste_expire_date>
<paste_private>2</paste_private>
<paste_format_long>None</paste_format_long>
<paste_format_short>text</paste_format_short>
<paste_url>https://pastebin.com/asdfasdf</paste_url>
<paste_hits>0</paste_hits>
</paste>
...
```

Comment: Looking at your sample data, the problem might be that your `<paste>` elements aren't contained within a single root element.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the xml structure then try BeautifulSoup.

If your paste is a string named pastebin_string the it would be something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pastebin_string, "html.parser")
pastes = soup.find_all("paste").
for paste in pastes:
    key = paste.find("paste_key")
    print(key.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me. Thanks @john-gordon for pointing that out

```
        x = self.apiobject.pastes_by_user(api_dev_key=self.DEVKEY, api_user_key=self.userkey)

        x = x.split("</paste>")
        x = [y + "</paste>\r\n" for y in x]

        for key in x[:-1]:
            paste = ET.fromstring(key)
            self.pastekeys.append(paste.find('paste_key').text)
```